# How to clone wiringPi after git.drogon.net got inaccesible

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, wiringpi

How do I get the source code for the wiringPi library now that Gordon has pulled git.drogon.net?

I would like to pull the source using git but other options are possible.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and how to [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). **there is also a download button on github**

Comment: Why do you even want to clone wiringPi? just apt install it

Answer (score 2):

Just pull it from [`https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi`](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi).
It seems to be an unofficial fork of the original repo by Gordon.

Just do:

```
git clone https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi.git
```

Or just install it using `apt-get` on raspian:

```
sudo apt-get install wiringpi
```

I don't believe there is any reason to build the source yourself if you are not actively developing the wiringPi library. Also if you really need a backup of the library:

```
sudo apt-get download wiringpi
```

This will download .deb for the raspberrypi and allows you to save it till perpetuity.

---

Downloading wiringpi will result in a .deb package. You can use any archive manager such as 7Zip, Ark and WinRar to open that file and open the `data.tar.xz` which contains all files you need to link against the library. Such as `libwiringPi.so` in the `lib` directory and all the .h files in the `include` directory needed.

---

Or download it from [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wiringpi), under the *Package information* header there is an option to find the *latest upload*, this being [2.50-0ubuntu1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wiringpi/2.50-0ubuntu1) at the time of writing. This allows you to download the complete source by downloading [wiringpi_2.50.orig.tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+sourcefiles/wiringpi/2.50-0ubuntu1/wiringpi_2.50.orig.tar.gz)`

Or here on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/wiringpi) (this one is for groovy but principle still stands). Just download the source package on the right hand side of the site.

---

*And for the love of god stop bothering Gordon, the guy got burned out by the 
community and bothering him about a downed repo is not really helping **him** getting better.*

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the official copy of wiringPi is unavailable. When Gordon announced on Aug. 6th that he was no longer supporting wiringPi, he said he would continue to make the final release available (http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-deprecated).

However, the download server is not responding: When you go to the download page (http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/), it links to a server (git.drogon.net) that responds only

"git.drogon.net is temporarily unavailable. Please look for alternatives for wiringPi, etc. -Gordon"

I wrote to Gordon about this, but he hasn't replied yet. Since one of the reasons he said he quit offering wiringPi was because of too many emails from the community, I'm not holding my breath waiting for an answer.

This is why I said you can't get an official download. Gordon's announcement claimed that unofficial forks of the code can be found on github, but I haven't found any.

It may be that your best bet is to find someone who downloaded the official version before August, and would be willing to give you a copy of the tarball.